# spring security - Using PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken

Tags: java, spring-security

I've been trying Spring Security and after built a little prototype I have a funny scenario here that I can't figure out what I've done wrong.

It's a simple scenario where:
The user requests a trial.
The system generates a random String and sends a link with this string.
the user clicks on the link (or copy in the address bar in his/her browser) and the system redirects to set a password.

Everything works alright until the point when the user click the link.
The link is mapped using Spring MVC and my method only checks if the string is valid and not expired. Then using a PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken I log the user in and redirect to a password page. (See code below)

```
try {
    SecurityIdentification securityIdentification = securityService.loadSecurityId(securityId);
    User user = securityIdentification.getUser();
    PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken = new PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken(user.getEmailAddress(), securityId, user.getAuthorities());

    Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(preAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken);

    SecurityContext securityContext = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
    securityContext.setAuthentication(authentication);

    return "redirect:/password";

} catch (AuthenticationException e) {
    model.addAttribute("message", e.getMessage());
    model.addAttribute(new TrialForm());
    return "trial";
}
```

Also, here it is my context xml. I'm just putting the beans to save space. :)

```
<context:component-scan
    base-package="xyz.com.security" />

<security:http
    pattern="/trial/**"
    security="none" />

<security:http>
    <security:intercept-url
        pattern="/**"
        access="ROLE_USER" />

    <security:anonymous
        username="guest"
        granted-authority="ROLE_GUEST"
        enabled="true" />

    <security:form-login default-target-url="/dashboard" />
    <security:logout />
    <security:remember-me />
</security:http>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="daoAuthenticationProvider" />
    <security:authentication-provider
        ref="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean
    id="authenticator"
    class="xyz.com.security.Authenticator" />

<bean
    id="encoder"
    class="org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder" />

<bean
    id="daoAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider"
>
    <property
        name="userDetailsService"
        ref="authenticator" />
    <property
        name="passwordEncoder"
        ref="encoder" />
</bean>

<bean
    id="preAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"
    class="org.springframework.security.web.authentication.preauth.PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationProvider"
>
    <property
        name="preAuthenticatedUserDetailsService"
        ref="authenticator" />
</bean>
```

I have implements UserDetails as my entity "user" and GrantedAuthority as my entity "role". I've also implemented AuthenticationUserDetailsService which looks up and loads my user in the database.

Now... Finally... :D
The problem I'm facing is that When I pre-authenticate my user using the code above and redirect to the password page, spring security shows me the login page instead of password page as I expect the user to be already authenticated.

I've seen a few implementations and my one is very similar. The only difference is the AbstractPreAuthenticatedProcessingFilter that some of the implementations use but I couldn't see a reason to implement myself.

Would you guys have any ideas of what I'm missing?
Any help will be great. Thank you.

---------** UPDATE **----------
Here is the stacktrace.

```
    11:19:05,874 DEBUG [org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Invoking afterPropertiesSet() on bean with name 'redirect:/password'
11:19:05,875 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Rendering view [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.RedirectView: name 'redirect:/password'; URL [/password]] in DispatcherServlet with name 'myapp'
11:19:05,878 DEBUG [org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Successfully completed request
11:19:05,881 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=oos2stZVidFUWNWLtjCuFfaH.undefined
11:19:05,884 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Checking match of request : '/password'; against '/trial/**'
11:19:05,887 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:19:05,889 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
11:19:05,891 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@23bdc15c. A new one will be created.
11:19:05,897 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:19:05,899 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
11:19:05,901 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
11:19:05,903 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 5 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
11:19:05,905 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 6 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
11:19:05,907 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 7 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'RememberMeAuthenticationFilter'
11:19:05,909 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 8 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
11:19:05,911 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Populated SecurityContextHolder with anonymous token: 'org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90545b24: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: oos2stZVidFUWNWLtjCuFfaH.undefined; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS'
11:19:05,916 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 9 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
11:19:05,917 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 10 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
11:19:05,919 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /password at position 11 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
11:19:05,921 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /password; Attributes: [ROLE_USER]
11:19:05,923 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Previously Authenticated: org.springframework.security.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationToken@90545b24: Principal: anonymousUser; Credentials: [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: org.springframework.security.web.authentication.WebAuthenticationDetails@12afc: RemoteIpAddress: 127.0.0.1; SessionId: oos2stZVidFUWNWLtjCuFfaH.undefined; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ANONYMOUS
11:19:51,333 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1355177991333 sessioncount 0
11:19:51,339 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 6 expired sessions: 0
11:20:01,346 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) Start expire sessions StandardManager at 1355178001346 sessioncount 1
11:20:01,351 DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase] (ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[jboss.web]]) End expire sessions StandardManager processingTime 5 expired sessions: 0
11:20:20,500 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter@50d9370d, returned: -1
11:20:20,512 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Voter: org.springframework.security.access.vote.AuthenticatedVoter@64ad5ff2, returned: 0
11:20:20,520 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Access is denied (user is anonymous); redirecting to authentication entry point: org.springframework.security.access.AccessDeniedException: Access is denied
    at org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased.decide(AffirmativeBased.java:83) [spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.access.intercept.AbstractSecurityInterceptor.beforeInvocation(AbstractSecurityInterceptor.java:206) [spring-security-core-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:84) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:103) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:113) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.rememberme.RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(RememberMeAuthenticationFilter.java:139) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:54) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:45) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.ui.DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.doFilter(DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter.java:91) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:183) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:87) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:342) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:192) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:160) [spring-security-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:346) [spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:259) [spring-web-3.1.3.RELEASE.jar:3.1.3.RELEASE]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:275) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:161) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.jboss.as.jpa.interceptor.WebNonTxEmCloserValve.invoke(WebNonTxEmCloserValve.java:50) [jboss-as-jpa-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:153) [jboss-as-web-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:155) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:368) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:877) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:671) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:930) [jbossweb-7.0.13.Final.jar:]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [rt.jar:1.6.0_34]

11:20:20,595 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Set encoding to ISO-8859-1
11:20:20,597 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.HttpSessionRequestCache] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) DefaultSavedRequest added to Session: DefaultSavedRequest[http://localhost:8080/myapp/password]
11:20:20,600 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Calling Authentication entry point.
11:20:20,602 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.DefaultRedirectStrategy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Redirecting to 'http://localhost:8080/myapp/spring_security_login'
11:20:20,603 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:20:20,605 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
11:20:20,610 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Cookies] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Cookies: Parsing b[]: JSESSIONID=oos2stZVidFUWNWLtjCuFfaH.undefined
11:20:20,612 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.util.AntPathRequestMatcher] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Checking match of request : '/spring_security_login'; against '/trial/**'
11:20:20,615 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /spring_security_login at position 1 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'SecurityContextPersistenceFilter'
11:20:20,616 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT
11:20:20,618 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) No SecurityContext was available from the HttpSession: org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSessionFacade@23bdc15c. A new one will be created.
11:20:20,620 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /spring_security_login at position 2 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
11:20:20,622 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /spring_security_login at position 3 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
11:20:20,625 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) /spring_security_login at position 4 of 11 in additional filter chain; firing Filter: 'DefaultLoginPageGeneratingFilter'
11:20:20,628 DEBUG [org.apache.tomcat.util.http.Parameters] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) Set encoding to ISO-8859-1
11:20:20,630 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SecurityContext is empty or contents are anonymous - context will not be stored in HttpSession.
11:20:20,633 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) SecurityContextHolder now cleared, as request processing completed
```

Answer (score 0):

My experience with Spring Security is little, but I suspect that your user has not ROLE_USER, so he is redirected to login. You should add new security:intercept-url section for /password.

Comment: when I create my user, I add _ROLE_USER_ and _ROLE_ADMIN_. In my database I have a simple table relationship user - role and my authenticator bean that implements the **AuthenticationUserDetailsService<PreAuthenticatedAuthenticationToken>** loads the GrantedAuthorites and everything. I didn't add an intercept-url for password because it's already covered by intercept-url /**

Comment: Check the logs. Does spring throw a `AccessDeniedException` or `AuthenticationException` when you redirect to the password page? If so, you have not provided the right authorities to the user. 
If you enable debug log level, you'll see a log right above the exception that shows the user in the current `SecurityContext` and the authorities granted to the user.

Comment: Yep, you got it right... My logs are not happy... `11:19:05,889 DEBUG [org.springframework.security.web.context.HttpSessionSecurityContextRepository] (http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080-1) HttpSession returned null object for SPRING_SECURITY_CONTEXT`. It's coming back as **anonymous** after I set the user with the preAuth token and redirect to the password page.

Answer (score 0):

The error is somewhere in the code we cannot see.

The pattern `"/**"` includes `/password` so SS requires a `SecurityContext` with a `ROLE_USER` authority. Enable SS debug logs and show us the output (incl. exceptions).